# What does it mean to "do an updatedb" on Linux CentOS

Tags: linux, centos

It says:

> And then do an updatedb and locate php.spec.

at http://www.howtoforge.com/installing_php_mssql_centos5.0

But what does it actually mean to "do an updatedb"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a Terminal, xterm, or similar and at the shell (bash, zsh, tcsh, ...) `$` prompt type...

```
man updatedb
```

... tells a lot of details.

The shell command `locate` depends on a database that is built by `updatedb` - some (most?) Linux'es runs the update every now and then.
If you wish to find a recently added file the `updatedb` can be done manually to catch the change.

So `locate php.spec` will find the 'php.spec' file, if it exists (a bit depending on file attributes though).

Answer (score 1):

Your HOWTO page is asking you to find where the php.spec file has been placed on your system.

The `locate` command will give you the full path to where the file has been installed.

Before running the `locate` command you need to update a list of files installed on your machine. To do this, as Hannu says, you run the command `updatedb`.  Once that process has finished (may take a couple of minutes or longer) then the `locate` command now has a complete up-to-date list of all your files on your system, including the newly installed php.spec file.

If `locate` and/or `updatedb` then you need to install them.

```
yum install slocate
```

OR

```
yum install mlocate
```

Will install those tools for you.

Once installed.

updatedb && locate php.spec

Will give you the path to the php.spec file you need to use in the next section of the guide.

Comment: I think this should have been the excepted answer. The accepted answer pertains to Debian sytem, the OP (in the title implies a CentOS system).